# material UI AutoComplete dropdown position

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui

how to disable autocomplete auto position?

want to show autocomplete options always bottom.

https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-t1luy?file=/demo.js

Answer (score 6):

Add popper props with modifiers:

```
<Autocomplete
  id="combo-box-demo"
  options={top100Films}

  /* ...yourProps */

  componentsProps={{
    popper: {
      modifiers: [
        {
          name: 'flip',
          enabled: false
        },
        {
           name: 'preventOverflow',
           enabled: false
         }
      ]
    }
  }}

  renderInput={(params) => (
    <TextField {...params} label="Combo box" variant="outlined" />
  )}
/>
```

Comment: Thank you, finally a solution that works. 

**Note of others**: For this to work, I had to upgrade to the latest version of `@mui/material`, which as of now, is `5.14.2`

Answer (score 2):

For the current latest version of MaterialUI, you can use the property `disablePortal` to achieve behavior when a popup with a list of options will always be shown on the bottom

Should be something like this

```
<Autocomplete
  id="combo-box-demo"
  options={top100Films}
  getOptionLabel={(option) => option.title}
  style={{ width: 300, paddingTop: 300 }}

  disablePortal={true}

  renderInput={(params) => (
    <TextField {...params} label="Combo box" variant="outlined" />
  )}
/>
```

Comment: did you test it? in my case 'disablePortal' does not alter the dropdown position behavior

Answer (score 2):

property disablePortal={true} works for me.

Answer (score 2):

For MUI v5, if you're trying to use the "disablePortal" prop, as it should work on previous versions of MUI, what worked for me is to simply remove the "disablePortal" prop, which automatically set the placement of the dropdown list to "bottom" for any number of elements in the list.

Comment: This prop seems to have no effect of the options position in MUI v5 whether set to true or false

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

You can wrap your `Autocomplete` component with a `div` and add the below style

```
    <div style={{display: 'flex', alignItems: 'flex-end'}}>
        <Autocomplete
          id="combo-box-demo"
          options={top100Films}
          getOptionLabel={(option) => option.title}
          style={{ width: 300}}
          renderInput={(params) => (
            <TextField {...params} label="Combo box" variant="outlined" />
          )}
        />
    </div>
```

Comment: That does not work for me